# Using matlab function "pdf"

Tags: matlab, probability, gaussian

I have got a Gaussian mixture distribution object `obj` of 64 dimensions and would like to put it in the `pdf` function to find out the probability of certain point.

Yet when I type `pdf(obj,obj.mu(1,:))` to test the object it yield a very high probability (like 2.4845e+069)

And it does not make sense, cause probability should lies between zero and one.

Is my matlab having any problem?

p.s.
even `pdf(obj,obj.mu(1,:)+obj.Sigma(1,1)*rand())` yield a high probability (2.1682e+069)

Comment: The probability density function does not provide the probability of a certain value. To answer your question it would be helpful if you posted the creation of `obj`.

Comment: @Deve obj is generated through the standard *gmdistribution* function.

Comment: I anticipated that. What parameters did you pass to that function?

Comment: @Deve The parameters are estimated by using EM algorithm. The code I used is the code written by Mo Chen, this is the [link](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26184-em-algorithm-for-gaussian-mixture-model).

Comment: @Deve I have also tried the standard `gmdistribution.fit` function. It yield the same result. Following is the code: `obj = gmdistribution.fit(features',3)`
`pdf(obj, features(:,1)')`
 and the result is still very high `ans =  1.1505e+051`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: a probability density function does not always evaluate to 1, it merely *integrates* to 1 over its domain.

Moreover, what you are seeing is the [problem of singularities](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~rcollins/CSE586Spring2010/papers/prmlMixturesEM.pdf) (see page 434, figure 9.7) when fitting a gaussian mixture model. Some component collapsing onto a single data point inevitably causes the variance to go to 0 and the PDF to explode. This is often encountered in gaussian mixture models because it is not log-convex and there are lots of local maxima in the likelihood function. We try to find a well-behaved local maximum that performs well, and the singularities are particularly bad cases.

When you see this, you will want to rerun the algorithm with different starting points or to reduce the number of components you are using. The book above also recommends just resetting the particular component to a different value.

Another approach would be to use a Bayesian approach by adopting a prior or regularization term for your parameters, which will penalize outlandish values such as 0 sigma parameters.

You can indirectly control the first part using different starting values in `gmdistribution.fit`. For the second part, you can use the `Regularize` argument: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution.fit.html

Comment: Thanks very much! Very detail explanation! I checked the covariance matrix and found that there are many zero entries. After applying the regularize term the probability kind of making sense now. Yet the value becomes very low: `pdf(obj, obj.mu(1,:)) = 1.4080e-052` is it normal?

Comment: Yes, the PDF will be very small when you have many dimensions. You may want to work with the log prob to avoid underflowing.