# Interpretation of MATLAB's NaiveBayses 'posterior' function

Tags: matlab, probability, classification

After we created a Naive Bayes classifier object `nb` (say, with multivariate multinomial (`mvmn`) distribution), we can call `posterior` function on testing data using `nb` object. This function has 3 output parameters:

> [post,cpre,logp] = posterior(nb,test)

I understand how `post` is computed and the meaning of that, also `cpre` is the predicted class, based on the maximum over posterior probabilities for each class.

The question is about `logp`. It is clear how it is computed (logarithm of the PDF of each pattern in test), but I don't understand the meaning of this measure and how it can be used in the context of Naive Bayes procedure. Any light on this is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logp` you are referring to is the [log likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_likelihood), which is one way to measure how good a model is fitting. We use log probabilities to prevent computers from underflowing on very small floating-point numbers, and also because adding is faster than multiplying.

If you learned your classifier several times with different starting points, you would get different results because the likelihood function is not log-concave, meaning there are local maxima that you would get stuck in. If you computed the likelihood of the posterior on your original data you would get the likelihood of the model. Although the likelihood gives you a good measure of how one set of parameters fits compared to another, you need to be careful that you're not [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

In your case, you are computing the likelihood on some unobserved (test) data, which gives you an idea of how well your learned classifier is fitting on the data. If you were trying to learn this model based on the test set, you would pick the parameters based on the highest test likelihood; however in general when you're doing this it's better to use a [validation set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_set). What you are doing here is computing [predictive likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution).

Computing the log likelihood is not limited to Naive Bayes classifiers and can in fact be computed for any Bayesian model (gaussian mixture, latent dirichlet allocation, etc).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Since PDF of each test point is in [0,1] range then `logp` would be in (-infinity, 0]. As I understand the higher this measure (logp) the better our fitted classifier predicts the new pattern. Is it correct? Also am I right that predicted class is chosen according to the maximum of all posterior probabilities? Or we take the logs in this case as well? Thanks

Comment: `logp` can be positive if you have things such as [singularities](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15563245/586086). A PDF only integrates to 1, it can evaluate to be greater than 1. What you are doing here is computing [predictive likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_predictive_distribution).

Comment: thanks, the links are very useful. So, simply putting, if we for the new data point we observe `logp = x`, can we make any inference from this `x` value or we can say only some relative information compared to other points? I.e. if x is large negative, close to zero or large positive

Comment: You usually compute the likelihood on an entire set of data, not just a single point. It's pretty meaningless for a single point, unless for example in a mixture model you want to compute which mixture component was mostly likely to generate it.

Comment: Hm..That, actually was the initial question... Matlab documentation explains:
[POST,CPRE,LOGP] = POSTERIOR(NB,TEST) returns LOGP, an N-by-1
%    vector containing estimates of the log of the probability density
%    function (PDF). LOGP(I) is the log of the PDF of point I. The PDF
%    value of point I is the sum of
%
%         Prob(point I | class J) * Pr{class J}
%
%    taken over all classes.